# How do I combine two OR statements in one line?

Tags: php, syntax

I've got these two lines I'd like shortened to one, if possible:

```
defined( 'INIT' ) OR $direct = true;
defined( 'INIT' ) OR include 'inc/router.php';
```

I tried

```
defined( 'INIT' ) OR include 'inc/router.php' AND $direct = true;
```

...but it doesn't work.

I'm adding security measures to a bunch of templates to disallow client direct access.

Comment: Why do you think you need to shorten 2 lines of code?

Comment: "I'm adding security measures to a bunch of templates to disallow client direct access." Put them outside the web root (i.e. your `public_html`, `httpdocs`, `public`, etc. folder) instead of this sort of patch job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I came up with. Any other suggestions would be appreciated.

```
if (!defined('INIT')) {$direct = TRUE; include 'inc/router.php';}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten it using the "Elvis" operator (`?:`), but the question is why? It certainly doesn't improve readability.

```
defined('INIT') ?: $direct = TRUE AND include 'file.php';
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested:

```
<?php

defined('INIT') OR ($direct = true AND include 'inc/router.php');
```

But I'd probably just stick to your if not defined multiline in your self-answer for readability.